# If I authorize someone to send as me though Exchange Online will I see the sent emails?

Tags: exchange, outlook, microsoft-office-365, mailbox, delegation

Lets assume I am the owner of the mailbox "george@example.com" and via the Exchange Online administration I allow the owner of "john@example.com" to send emails as "george@example.com" while I am out of office.

Will those emails be stored in the `Sent Items` folder of the "george@example.com" mailbox, or will they remain only in the "john@example.com" mailbox?

I am currently using Office 365 with Exchange Online and I send/receive emails via Outlook 365 and Outlook online.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question for everyone managing Exchange Online (or on-premises); how could someone vote to close it as "not reasonable business IT management practices" or "belonging on SuperUser"?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how the messages are being sent.

A shared mailbox can be configured to store a copy of messages sent in its name:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2015/03/03/want-more-control-over-sent-items-when-using-shared-mailboxes.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123981(v=exchg.160).aspx

Basically, you need to use the following command on the shared mailbox:

```
Set-Mailbox <MailboxName> -MessageCopyForSentAsEnabled  $true
```

The same can also be done for whoever is sending *on behalf* of you, instead of *as* you:

```
Set-Mailbox <MailboxName> -MessageCopyForSendOnBehalfEnabled  $true
```

However, this only applies to native Exchange clients (i.e. Outlook, OWA); if the user is sending via SMTP submission, sent messages are never stored by Exchange anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. In your answer you mention shared mailbox. Since shared mailbox is an technical term with ExchangeI would like to clairfy. I am not planning to use a "shared" mailbox I am planning to use a normal user mailbox and then give send permissions to an other mailbox. If I understand your answer even then if the delegated user sends as the original email through Outlook or Outlook Online the emails sent are going to be saved on the original mailbox's sent folder. Is that correct? Again thank you for your insight!

Comment: Yes, that setting is meant mainly for shared mailboxes, but it also applies to standard user mailboxes on which you are delegating send permissions.

Comment: Perfect! I am going to test this out during the weekend and will let you know! one last thing. Do you know how to implement the command you mentioned via the GUI of office 365 exchange admin?

Comment: This can't be done via GUI, only via PowerShell; if you need instructions on how to use remote PowerShell to manage Exchange Online, you'll find them here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj984289(v=exchg.160).aspx.

Comment: ok I will follow the links you provided. Again thank you for your help!

Comment: @Massimo, `-MessageCopyForSentAsEnabled` and `-MessageCopyForSendOnBehalfEnabled` do in fact only work with *Shared Mailboxes*. They do not work with regular Mailboxes and perhaps you should edit your answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Daniel You are right, answer edited.